# Switch sites icon is huge

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, favicon

The icon in switch sites input on SEDE is huge and overlaps with the placeholder making the "search" hard to read.

[image: Switch sites: [icon se]arch by name or url]

(Chrome 32.0.1700.76 m, IE11 - win8.1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to us pushing high DPI favicons earlier today, a fix is rolling out now.

Comment: Yup, those icons are sharper than ever, awesome!