# Realtime Questions page favicons need a serious diet

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, favicon, realtime-questions

[See for yourself](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime): (those are heavily cached, client side, so you might need to clear it)

> [image]

The icons are all 32x32 while they used to be 16x16 before. Either they need to shrink, or the text to get bigger, either will work.

I assume it's the same root cause as [this other report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217409/152859), can't be sure though.

Comment: And the high-res retina icons strike again.

Comment: i also get the big icons for Super User, Server Fault, etc.. Only Stackoverflow and Programmers is normal

Comment: @Jehof right, they're all huge, clear your cache... will update my post as well.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yeah i´ve done that. Now they are all bigger.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The real-time tab is not getting updated automatically on my side. Is that normal? Do you experience the same problem??

Comment: @Jehof realtime working fine for me, check your websockets. :)

Comment: yep thanks. will do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed in stackexchange.com build `2014.1.27.823`.

Comment: Excellent, CSS for the rescue!